# How to get SUM value in a array?

Tags: php

I have 2 elements which has the value of `member` which is `5`

I want to get the sum of all value of `member`

`[member] => 5` + `[member] => 5` = 10

The output should be **10**

This is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [membUid] => 0090000816
            [service_id] => 0
            [member] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [membUid] => 0090000867
            [service_id] => 0
            [member] => 5
        )

)
```

This is my code:

```
 foreach($result['content'] as $res){
     sum($res['member']);
 }
```

Comment: if `array_column` function is available, you can use it, then use `array_sum`, if not, just a simple `foreach`, just initialize a variable to hold the sum.

Comment: I already use `array_sum ` but it doest work

Comment: Where's attempted code of array_sum?

Comment: it doesn't work on multi leveled ones, `array_column` gets all the values from `member` values, then use the array `array_sum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($result as $res) {
   $sum += $res['member'];
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative solution, with `array_sum` & `array_map` functions

```
echo array_sum(array_map(function($i){return $i["member"];},$result['content']));
```